# How can I solve the error too much recursion in my Chartcomponet in vue?

Tags: vue.js, debugging, recursion, axios, visualization

For my school project i am making a monitor system in which I visualise sensor data.This data is being updated every 5 seconds and is saved only for the session. this visualisation is done using the VUE.js framework. In this framework i use 3 components I have a dashboard component, a widget component and a Grapcomponent. My problem is that when i first started visualising the sensor data i just had one data source so there was no need for the graphcomponent to be able to be scaleable. This was my first iteration of the graphcomponent that was not scaleable

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="temperatureData">
      <p>Temperature: {{ temperatureData.temp }}</p>
      <p>Timestamp: {{ formatTimestamp(temperatureData.timestamp) }}</p>
    </div>
    <canvas ref="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VinAIDataService from "../service/VinAIDataService";
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js/auto';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment'; // Import the date adapter

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      temperatureData: null,
      historicalData: [], // Array to store historical data
      chart: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.retrieveData(); // Initial data retrieval
    this.setupAutoRefresh(); // Setup automatic refresh
  },
  methods: {
    async retrieveData() {
      // Retrieve and update data
      this.temperatureData = await VinAIDataService.retrieveTemperatureData();
      this.historicalData.push(this.temperatureData); // Save data to historical array
      this.updateChart();
    },
    formatTimestamp(timestamp) {
      return new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString();
    },
    setupAutoRefresh() {
      // Refresh data every 5 seconds (adjust as needed)
      this.refreshInterval = setInterval(() => {
        this.retrieveData();
      }, 5000);
    },
    updateChart() {
      const ctx = this.$refs.myChart;
      
      // Check if the canvas element is available
      if (!ctx) {
        return;
      }

      // Destroy the existing chart if it exists
      if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.destroy();
      }

      this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: this.historicalData.map(entry => new Date(entry.timestamp)),
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Temperature',
              data: this.historicalData.map(entry => entry.temp),
              borderColor: 'blue',
              fill: false,
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            x: {
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                displayFormats: {
                  minute: 'HH:mm',
                  hour: 'HH:mm',
                },
              },
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Timestamp',
              },
            },
            y: {
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Temperature',
              },
            },
          },
        },
        plugins: [registerables], // Register Chart.js plugins
      });
    },
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    // Clear the interval when the component is unmounted
    clearInterval(this.refreshInterval);

    // Destroy the chart
    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.destroy();
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

But now i do want it to be scaleable I thought i could achieve this by calling the chart component in my dashboard component and passing data to my graphcomponent so that it does not matter wat kind of data it is but when i do this i get the error too much recursion.

this is my updated genericchart that is called in the dashboardcomponent and which causes too much recursion

```
// GenericChart.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas ref="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js/auto';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';

export default {
  props: {
    chartOptions: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chart: null,
      shouldUpdateChart: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createChart();
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    this.destroyChart();
  },
  watch: {
    chartData: {
      handler() {
        // Set the flag to true to indicate that the chart should be updated
        this.shouldUpdateChart = true;
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    createChart() {
      const ctx = this.$refs.myChart;
      if (ctx) {
        this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: this.chartData,
          options: this.chartOptions,
          plugins: [registerables],
        });
      }
    },

    updateChart() {
      if (this.chart && this.shouldUpdateChart) {
        // Destroy the existing chart to avoid memory leaks
        this.chart.destroy();

        // Create a new chart with updated data
        this.createChart();

        // Optionally, you can directly update the existing chart data without destroying and recreating
        // this.chart.data.labels = this.chartData.labels;
        // this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = this.chartData.datasets[0].data;

        // Update the chart to reflect the changes
        this.chart.update();

        // Reset the flag after updating the chart
        this.shouldUpdateChart = false;
      }
    },

    destroyChart() {
      if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.destroy();
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and this is my dashbaord component

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <ChartComponent title="Temperature" :chartData="temperatureChartData" :chartOptions="temperatureChartOptions" />
    <ChartComponent title="Side Kettle Temperature" :chartData="sideKettleChartData" :chartOptions="sideKettleChartOptions" />
    <!-- Add more ChartComponent instances as needed -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VinAIDataService from "../service/VinAIDataService";
import ChartComponent from '../components/GenericChart.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    ChartComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      temperatureChartData: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Temperature',
            data: [],
            borderColor: 'blue',
            fill: false,
          },
        ],
      },
      sideKettleChartData: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Side Kettle Temperature',
            data: [],
            borderColor: 'green',
            fill: false,
          },
        ],
      },
      // Add more data sets as needed
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async retrieveData() {
      try {
        
        const temperatureData = await VinAIDataService.retrieveTemperatureData();
        const sideKettleTempData = await VinAIDataService.retrieveSideKettleTempData();

        // Update chart data
        this.temperatureChartData.labels.push(new Date(temperatureData.timestamp));
        this.temperatureChartData.datasets[0].data.push(temperatureData.temp);

        this.sideKettleChartData.labels.push(new Date(sideKettleTempData.timestamp));
        this.sideKettleChartData.datasets[0].data.push(sideKettleTempData.temp);
        
        // Add more data sets as needed

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    },
    setupAutoRefresh() {
      // Check if the interval is already set up
      if (!this.refreshInterval) {
        // Refresh data every 5 seconds (adjust as needed)
        this.refreshInterval = setInterval(() => {
          this.retrieveData();
        }, 5000);
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.retrieveData();
    this.setupAutoRefresh();
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.refreshInterval);
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.dashboard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
}

/* Add any additional styles as needed */
</style>
```

The methods that send the data are *retrieveTemperatureData* and *retrieveSideKettleTempData* these get the data every 5 seconds and then set autorefresh is used to refresh the data. I thought that this was causing the error but when i deconstruct it and make it impossible for that to make a loop I still get the error.

I knew that is error most of time is cause by an infinite loop so i started searching for it. But after going threw all the lines of code I still could not find the infinte loop in my code.
I hope you can help me find out what is causing the error and that you can help me find a proper solution.